# Delay in data - updated opening hours

Tags: google-my-business-api

I collect opening hours from google my business api but there seems to be a delay in the data.

One of my customers updated the opening hours 24 hours ago and still the data that i collect from the api shows the old opening hours.

I have seen that people talk about delays with reviews but that seems more understandable but for the opening hours that clearly shows updated on the business card when searching on google but not when collecting from api feels strange.

Any one else seen this or know a solution?